# Why isn't my Makefile creating an executable?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'll be honest here, my understanding of the following code is fairly limited. However, to the best of my knowledge it should be creating some sort of executable file so that I can "test" the program. But I'm either not sure what the executable will look like, or I'm not sure what how to run it. Or something isn't working. All the makefile does is create a testBSTree.o and I don't really know what to do with said file.

```
#  Makefile
#    a makefile for the stack example.
#

#            SHELL =    /bin/sh

#              TOP = .
#      CURRENT_DIR = .

#              CPP = /lib/cpp $(STD_CPP_DEFINES)
              CXX  = g++

#        CCOPTIONS =
#           CFLAGS = $(CDEBUGFLAGS) $(CCOPTIONS) $(ALLDEFINES)
#           RM_CMD = $(RM) *.o core

SRCS=   testBSTree.cpp  \
    BSTree2.cpp

OBJS=   testBSTree.o    \
    BSTree2.o       

testBSTree.o:   BSTree2.h

BSTree2.o:  BSTree2.h      #?

#link.o:    link.h                  #?

PROGRAMS = testBSTree

all::  $(PROGRAMS)


testBSTree: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)
#$(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDOPTIONS) $(LOCAL_LIBRARIES) $(LDLIBS)  $(EXTRA_LOAD_FLAGS)

clean::
    $(RM) testBSTree

latex::
    latex BSTree2.tex

###########################################################################
# common rules for all Makefiles - do not edit

emptyrule::

clean::
        rm *.o
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Put your final rule *first* (thats the rule that generates your program). Make builds the first target that is out of date, and in this case, your program is *not* it (but it should be). Putting it after the `all::` rule is fine. Your `testBSTree.o:` rule should be *after* your `all::` and `testBSTree:` rules (the latter, btw, should be `$(PROGRAMS):`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
make all
```

to compile everything.

Or put the `all::` target ahead of `testBSTree.o:`, then you can just type `make`. If you don't specify a target, `make` defaults to the first target in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run it with
    make all

Otherwise as Make will just pick your first target 
    testBSTree.o:   BSTree2.h

Finding out that testBSTree.o is not up to date, build it and happily quit having its work done.

As an alternative you might want to put the all target as the first one, so you just have to run make. That's the way it is usally done.

Comment: Thank you. This was a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Makefile, it works for me:

```
OBJS=testBSTree.o BSTree2.o

PROGRAMS = testBSTree

all:  $(PROGRAMS)

testBSTree: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm *.o
```

(Note that the indented lines should be intended with a tab, not with spaces!)

Comment: So this just forces it to make all instead of just the first one correct?

Comment: If you don't give any arguments to make, it will choose the first target by default... in the above Makefile, all: is the first target, so yes.